# Counting unique values in a pandas dataframe column consisting mixed values of strings and list of strings

Tags: python, pandas, unique

I would like to count the total unique values in a specific column of a data frame. The column looks like the following:

`df['column']=([one, two], three, four, [one,five], three])`

The desired output would be: 5

I tried `df['column'].nunique()` but since there are lists in the column it didn't work.

I tried the `Counter` method in a loop but I was not able to get the total unique count but instead I got unique count per line.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do:

```
df['column'].explode().nunique()

5
```